# Онлайн трансляция на сайте

Tags: видео, веб-служба, трансляция

Ищу сервис, который позволит организовать онлайн трансляцию через простую веб камеру. Самое важное - чтобы была возможность интегрировать код плеера с онлайн трансляцией к себе на сайт. Из той массы сайтов, что дают возможность онлайн трансляции, ни один не даёт её разместить на стороннем сайте. Как быть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне по нраву [ЯTV](http://yatv.ru/).

Есть ещё [LiveStream.com](http://livestream.com/) и [justin.tv](http://justin.tv)

Answer (score 0):

Если делать всё у себя, то 
haxevideo

Comment: Такой вариант точно не подойдет, нужно готовое решение, на подобие указанных выше.

Answer (score 0):

Так youtube же? (или в 12 году у них еще не было онлайн трансляций?)
А у ятв (который видимо стал eagle platform) какие цены? Кто-нибудь в курсе?
Я пока только один раз пользовалась [facecast.net](http://facecast.net), у них от 990 р (на сегодня) самая дешевая трансляция (ну и подписки) 
У [comdi](http://comdi.ru) тоже можно, но там тоже цены не понятны и даже по звонку просто сказать "сколько стоит мастер-класс показывать" им нужно записать данные, потом считать.

Comment: нет, не получится у comdi. Они только под ключ делают... и от 40т.р. за однокамерную трансляцию :(

Comment: (пропал комментарий...) У comdi не получится, они только "под ключ" делают, в смысле приехать со своими камерами. И от 40тр. с одной камеры. 
Извините за дезинформацию выше